# How to escape the backslash "\" character in jquery inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to escape the `escape char` (`\`) to allow a user to input its username of Active Directory (`DOMAIN\username`), but it wont include the character in the input field.

I've used `\`, `\\`, `\\\` and `\\\\` in the `mask`, and none works. Also tried with the function `escapeRegex()`, but have had no success.

How can this be achieved?

**JS:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend($.inputmask.defaults.aliases, {
        'ACTIVE-DIRECTORY': {
            mask: function(a) {
                return a.domain + '\\\\*{1,20}';
            },
            greedy: false,
            definitions: {
                '*': {
                    validator: '[A-Za-z\u0410-\u044F\u0401\u04510-9]',
                    cardinality: 1,
                    casing: 'lower'
                }
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:**

This is what it shows in HTML:

[image: input field]

Answer (score 0):

how you try to write your directive path to with encoded char?

```
(function ($) {
var dicrectory = encodeURIComponent(directory_path);
    $.extend($.inputmask.defaults.aliases, {
        dicrectory: {
            mask: function(a) {
                return a.domain + '\\\\*{1,20}';
            },
            greedy: false,
            definitions: {
                '*': {
                    validator: '[A-Za-z\u0410-\u044F\u0401\u04510-9]',
                    cardinality: 1,
                    casing: 'lower'
                }
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Remember do decode it on server side - or wherevere you want to use it.

Comment: How does this work? I can actually access the alias from HTML.